# auto login with AD user 16.04

Tags: 16.04, lightdm, auto-login

I configured ubuntu 16.04 with AD Domain user.
I use GNOME display manager and lightdm as login greeter
I can login with the domain user as normal after boot with no problem!
when i configure lightdm for auto login it fail due to authentication problems when reboot the machine, i got the login screen asking for password.
switching from AD user to local user and back working fine (i.e not ask for password)

i read a bunch of treads how to configure the lightdm for autologin, and from my reaults its working nice. 
even if i login with the domain user then restart the lightdm service , the auto login works perfect.

any help......